# TFS Shortcut to Queue New Build with Shelveset or Pending Changes

Tags: .net, tfs, build

I frequently like to build my current changes against the server build environment to ensure that when I'm ready to check-in, there won't be a pile up of errors to sort through due to my local environment differing from the server. The only workflow I know of for this is the following.

- Go to Pending Changes
- Create a Shelve Set
- Go to Builds
- Queue New Build
- Set Build Type to Latest Sources Plus Shelve Set
- Select Desired Shelve Set
- Select Queue

When you're queuing more than one build a day this gets tiresome. Is there a quicker way?

The holy grail would be a Queue New Build with Pending Changes option on the Build Definition context menu but I'll settle for anything that takes any number of steps out of the above workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a script to speed it up. You could try the [shelve command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6y8ezzs.aspx) followed by the [start command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181742.aspx).

```
$ tf shelve HelloWorld_TestMe c:\projects\*.cs /recursive
$ TFSBuild start http://myserver:8080/DefaultCollection /builddefinition:"AdventureWorks\Nightlies" /droplocation:"\\computername\buildDrops" /shelveset HelloWorld_TestMe
```

If that works, you could create an [External Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9814d200(v=vs.100).aspx) for it in Visual Studio so it shows up under the Tools menu. Then you could assign a hotkey to it. See Tool->External Tools.

Answer (score -1):

Use a gated check-in. That accomplishes roughly the same thing.

Comment: Just because the build succeeds, that does not mean I desire to check-in.